# My program asks user to enter password and if user enters wrong password, he gets five tries, and afterwards the program tells its over

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting wrong output. The loop is not breaking, even when the user re-entered the correct password. And it's not displaying login is successful when user entered the right password.

```
count = 0
password = input('Enter password: ')
while password != 'abcdefghijkl' and count <= 5:
    password_renter = input('Enter the password: ')
    count = count + 1
    if password_renter == 'abcdefghijkl' and password == 'abcdefghijkl':
        print('login successful')
        break
    if password_renter != 'abcdefghijkl' and count > 5:
        print('Chances over')
```

Comment: You're never updating the original password, not can that condition ever be true?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I just need to verify the password here. And the while loop must break if the user enters correct password within the five tries and must show login successful. I don't know what mistake I did.

Comment: I'd recommend using e.g. http://pythontutor.com/, SO isn't here for basic debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad behavior to use two different variable for the same purpose, in this case I saw `password_enter` and `password_renter`. I would just reuse one of them, at some point it breaks the loop.

```
attempts = 6
correct = "abcdefghijkl"
while (attempts > 0):
    password = input("Enter Password: ")
    if password == correct:
        print("login successful.")
        attempts = 0 
        ##function to execute when logged in
    else:
        attempts -= 1
        print("Attempts left: " + str(attempts))
```

Comment: Your code worked.  Thanks. The only mistake you did is string and int can't be combined together in the final print stmt you wrote. I converted attempts to str(attempts) and it worked fine.

Comment: @kalium Ohh maybe its just different version of python, I'll edit it now, if you think it's good, consider marking as answer.

Comment: Yeah. I am using Python 3.7 There is nothing wrong in your code except for that one minor glitch. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You enter inside the while loop only password is not equal to 'abcdefghijkl'. Thus when you are going to check it inside the while loop to see if password_renter and password are equal, it is always going to be False since the right side is False.

I suggest minimal change. However, I am not sure if this is what you wanted. Please test it at your end.

```py
count = 0
password = input('Enter password: ')
while count <= 5:
    password_renter = input('Enter the password: ')
    count = count + 1
    if password_renter == 'abcdefghijkl' and password == 'abcdefghijkl':
        print('login successful')
        break
    if password_renter != 'abcdefghijkl' and count > 5:
        print('Chances over')
```